# load data csv file to live server from desktop

Tags: mysql

this is my query for load data to mysql from csv. Here I have csv file in desktop and want to load data to my live server. This is possible to load in live server? Thanks in advance

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL
    INFILE 'C:/Users/Home/Desktop/IPLOCATION.CSV'
INTO TABLE
    `iplocation`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

Comment: You will need to transfer CSV file to server prior to that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No it is not possible, your server wont resolve desktop client path

Comment: LOAD DATA LOCAL does exactly that

Answer (score 2):

I have used permutations on the following to load CSV data (with Windows line endings)

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Country.csv' INTO TABLE `Country`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

From [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

> If LOCAL is specified, the file is read by the client program on the client host and sent to the server.

Comment: If LOCAL is specified, the file is read by the client program on the client host and sent to the server http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html. The file needs to be where the client end of the connection is; presumably the client end of the connection is on the desktop.